# Qt/Qml: Repeater vs. MapItemView for map elements

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtlocation

I want to populate a Qml Map with map elements (like MapCircle, ...) from a `QAbstractListModel`. There seem to be two Qml tools suitable for this, `MapItemView` [1] and `Repeater` [2]. The `Repeater` is more powerful (e.g. it allows nested models) - so is there any reason to use the `MapItemView` instead of a `Repeater`?

Regards,

[1] http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapitemview.html

[2] http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html

MapItemView source: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtlocation.git/tree/src/location/declarativemaps/qdeclarativegeomapitemview.cpp

Repeater source: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickrepeater.cpp

Comment: It is hard to judge from the documentation, but in most cases `Views` only instantiate as much as needed. So what is outside the `viewport` won't clutter your memory and initial creation time will be  better. The `Repeater` is dump. It will create `Items`s for every element in the model, no matter whether they will be shown or not.

Comment: Good point. I checked the source code: ``MapItemView`` adds all items to the Map. I am not sure what ``Repeater`` exactly does but probably it will also add the items just to the map. The map itself handles the visible item rendering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `MapItemView` for that.
Using `Repeater` works only when you create the `Map`, if you add elements in your model afterwards, no delegate will be added to the Map.

The fact that it works at first with `Repeater` but not afterwards is because:

- the `Repeater` parents his delegate to his parent which is the `Map`
- The `Map` object then scans its child items once when it's created (in a c++ function equivalent to `Component.onCompleted`)
- Upon this scan the children that are `MapItem`-derived objects are added to the map like when manually calling [`Map.addMapItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#addMapItem-method)
- Delegates that are created after that by the `Repeater` are just parented to the `Map` but not really "added" to it.

Since `MapItemView` is aware of the `Map` it can add the delegates to the `Map` when it creates them.

One of the limitation of `MapItemView` is that it only works with `QAbstractItemModel` and derived. That means it can work with a `ListModel` or a c++ model, but not with a "dumb" model like a js array or an integer as a model.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.